# Is there a way to code an event listener on a parent container to catch a focus/blur event on all its input elements?

Tags: javascript, html

This is an ugly example but could you please tell me if there is a way to get the `focus` event of the `input` elements (green border) to be caught by the parent table event listener, as the `change` events are, without assigning an event listener to each individual input element.

```js
document.querySelector('table.two').addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log('change event');
}, false);

document.querySelector('table.two').addEventListener('focus', () => {
  console.log('focus event');
}, false);
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
  border-top-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-top-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

td>div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(150, 150, 150);
  background-color: white;
}

tr.sel {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 3px rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

td>div.sel {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  border-color: blue;
}

input {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table class="two">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="sel">
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div class="sel"><input type='text'></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <div></div>
        <div><input type='text'></div>
        <div></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `focus` event does not bubble - it does not propagate to parents. Fortunately there is another event you can use that does bubble - `focusin`:

```
document.querySelector('table.two')
    .addEventListener( 'focusin', () => {
        console.log( 'focus event' ); 
    }, false );
```

For more on this see the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event

Comment: Thank you. I should have figured that out.  I skipped right over focusin when reading. And I assume focusout will bubble in place of blur also.

Comment: Yes, they added focusout just for that use-case