# JavaScript global event listener not working with focus event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

HTML

```
<input type="number" value="0" class="number" />
```

JS

```
function addGlobalEventListener(type, selector, callback) {
  document.addEventListener(type, (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches(selector)) callback(e)
  })
}

// "click" event WORKS (console logs out '0')
addGlobalEventListener("click", ".number", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
})

// "focus" event DOESN'T WORK (console doesn't log out anything -- not even an error).
addGlobalEventListener("focus", ".number", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

Focus event DOES work if I use a straightforward event listener:

```
// console logs out '0'
const number = document.querySelector(".number")
number.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

Can any one tell me what the problem is with the global event listener and 'focus'?

**EDIT**

Based on the answers I received, and with a little research, I found a way of modifying the original function so that it can be used for either e.g. 'focusin' and 'click':

```
function addGlobalEventListener(type, selector, callback, option = false) {
  document.addEventListener(
    type,
    (e) => {
      if (e.target.matches(selector)) callback(e)
    },
    option
  )
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="number" value="0" class="number" />
```

JS 'focusin' event

```
addGlobalEventListener(
  "focusin",
  ".number",
  (e) => {
    e.target.value = ""
  },
  true
)
```

HTML

```
<button class="button" type="button">Button</button>
```

JS 'click' event

```
addGlobalEventListener("click", ".button", (e) => {
  e.target.textContent = "Button clicked"
})
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to use the `focusin` event which bubbles since `focus` event does not. Link to [focusin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event) at MDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This illustrates the difference and may answer your question. It is `focus` versus `focusin` event concerning bubbling, such that the listener on the body element can't "hear" the `focus` event since it doesn't bubble. Just click in the box when run the snippet.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("focus", focusHandler, false);

document.body.addEventListener("focusin", focusinHandler, false);

function focusHandler(evt) {
  let e = evt.target;
  if (e.matches('input')) {
    console.log("Focus event heard by body from input!");
  } else {
    console.log("Focus event heard on body but not from input!");
  }
}

function focusinHandler(evt) {
  let e = evt.target;
  if (e.matches('input')) {
    console.log("Focusin event heard on body from input!");
  } else {
    console.log("Focusin event heard on body but not from input!");
  }
}
```

```css
input {
 width: 50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input></input>
 </div>
```

Comment: Don't know why my question and both answers were marked -1 - thanks!

Comment: Probably because someone wanted to mark it as a duplicate question and didn't get a chance to do so. Perhaps, it should be a duplicate because I just recalled asking the same thing almost four yeras ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677999/is-there-a-way-to-code-an-event-listener-on-a-parent-container-to-catch-a-focus). I don't know how to do those things or about priveleges to do so, and I think it likely just aggravates the OP because when it happens to me, many times, the proposed duplicate doesn't answer the question.

Comment: And sometimes one learns something new from the same question. For example, I never thought about the non-bubbling event being caught in the capturing phase, although I don't understand why the answer by @Unmitigated writes to console twice.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the focus event listener on the event capturing phase.

```js
document.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.outerHTML);
}, true);
```

```html
Focus here: <input type="number" value="0" class="number" />
```

Comment: Would you please explain why your example writes to console twice--once undefined and then the outerHTML? Thanks.

Comment: @Gary It doesn't log twice for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox. I have Brave also; I'll try it there now. ... Just tried it and it logs only once in Brave.